# Set color of second selected object

Tags: customization, theme

I know I can set the color of the active object (when displayed as wireframe) by setting the Active Object color in Themes/3D View.

However, if you select two objects (right click followed by shift + right-click), the second object is always a sort of orange. I could not find an option in the Themes that seemed to correspond to this "second selected object" color.

Is there a way to set this color?

Comment: it is object_selected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the color of selected objects in the 3D_view go to : ***User_Preferences->Theme->3D_view->Selected_object***

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The two different colours here are because there's an *active object* and *selected object*. If you have 1 object selected in your sceen, then that object is also the *active object*, if you have two..or three..or tens selected, then the last selected object is known as the *active object*.

Because @Chebhou already gives the UI version of an answer, here a scripted version which can be just as handy:

In the console:

```
theme = bpy.context.user_preferences.themes[0]
theme.view_3d.object_active = (0.8, 0.8, 0.5)
theme.view_3d.object_selected = (0.8, 0.8, 0.9)
```

[image]